# How to install an info file in Debian

Tags: debian, info

The command `info libc` outputs

> No menu item 'libc' in node '(dir)Top'

I think that the relevant info file is probably not installed. How can I install an info file in debian"?

Answer (score 1):

The glibc info documentation is in the *glibc-doc-reference* package, which is unfortunately non-free, so the non-free repository must be enabled if you want to install it via `apt`.

Comment: "non-free", What have you meant by that? Not public domain? AFAIK close to none of code of Linux based distros is by that definition "free". It says "GNU Free Documentation License, Version 1.3 or any later version published by the Free Software Foundation".

Comment: Why GNU free documentation license is incompatible with Debian distribution IIRC I've read somewhere but forgot.

Comment: Those documents covered by the GNU Free Documentation License (GFDL) which contain Invariant Sections do not meet the requirements of the Debian Free Software Guidelines (DFSG). See https://www.debian.org/vote/2006/vote_001 for more info or https://blogs.fsfe.org/greve/?p=85 for some analysis.

Comment: Thanks, the reading reminded me of interesting topics about licensing, I beg your pardon, Debian page has `Debian's answer is "no"`, so you are correct in context of `Debian` tag of the question, which I might had overlooked. Generally, any license not equivalent to public domain is not 100% free,

Answer (score 0):

Each package/utility installed in the system could have its own info page, but only if the maintainer added it, and also exist specialized documentation packages that install information database files for some commands (like `man`). In some distros, they are substituted with another format (Like in Ubuntu: `info libc` redirects to `man 7 libc` automatically).

In this case could be that the package `libc` does not include info doc files. You could check in the list of files of the package used in your distro version, or maybe you need to install the 'dev' version of `libc` to get its documentation. Also try `man libc`; maybe it exists in your system.

On the other hand, `info` without arguments will show the main index of installed info data files (and exists an `update-info-dir` command in the `install-info`package that rebuilds the info index of installed documentation files). Maybe there is not a `libc` as such, but a `C library` entry.